# what is the fundamental difference between jsonlite and rjson packages?

Tags: r, json

The rjson::fromJSON() reads a file incorrectly while jsonlite::fromJSON() reads it fine. Here's a sample example.

file test.json contents:

```
{"name": "Sanjay",
"unit_price": 130848,
"amount": 11,
"up_to_data_sales": 45725}
```

the `jsonlite` `fromJSON` outputs:

```
jsonlite::fromJSON("test.json")
$name
[1] "Sanjay"

$unit_price
[1] 130848

$amount
[1] 11

$up_to_data_sales
[1] 45725
```

But the same throws an error in `rjson` package.

```
rjson::fromJSON("test.json") 

Error in rjson::fromJSON("test.json") :   parseTrue: expected to see 'true' - likely an unquoted string starting with 't'.
```

1. Why is this error coming?
2. What is the reason `rjson` package was launched when `jsonlite` existed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well:

```
stringdist::stringdist("rjson", "jsonlite")
## [1] 5
```

That's a modest difference to begin with.

However, your assertion seems to be amiss:

```
library(magrittr)

rjson::fromJSON('{"name": "Sanjay",
"unit_price": 130848,
"amount": 11,
"up_to_data_sales": 45725}') %>% str()
## List of 4
##  $ name            : chr "Sanjay"
##  $ unit_price      : num 130848
##  $ amount          : num 11
##  $ up_to_data_sales: num 45725

jsonlite::fromJSON('{"name": "Sanjay",
"unit_price": 130848,
"amount": 11,
"up_to_data_sales": 45725}') %>% str()
## List of 4
##  $ name            : chr "Sanjay"
##  $ unit_price      : int 130848
##  $ amount          : int 11
##  $ up_to_data_sales: int 45725
```

Apart from `jsonlite` using a more diminutive data type for the numbers, they both parse the JSON fine.

So there's an issue with your file that you failed to disclose in the question.

A further incorrect assertion

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 bob  staff      2690 Jul 30  2007 rjson_0.1.0.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 bob  staff    400196 Dec  3  2013 jsonlite_0.9.0.tar.gz
```

not to mention:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 bob   staff   873843 Oct  4  2010 RJSONIO_0.3-1.tar.gz
```

`rjson` came first. (dir listings came from the CRAN mirror sitting next to me).

You can *actually read* about the rationale and impetus behind `jsonlite` here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.2805 (which I got off the CRAN page for `jsonlite`.

Answer (score 3):

1) Why is the error coming? - Error is due to the mistake in syntax

## rjson does not read the file if 'file=' command is not given whereas when reading the file using Jsonlite it is not required

```
 # For example:

 y <- rjson::fromJSON(file = "Input.json") 
 x <- jsonlite::fromJSON("Input.json")
```

2) What is the reason rjson package was launched when jsonlite existed?

First, rjson was launched before jsonlite and second, there is a difference in the way they read files:

For example, consider the following input:

{
   "id": 1,
   "prod_info": [
      {
         "product": "xyz",
         "brand": "pqr",
         "price": 500
      },
      {
         "product": "abc",
         "brand": "klm",
         "price": 5000
      }
   ]
}

prod_info in the above input is a list with 2 vectors. But jsonlite reads it in the form of dataframe while rjson reads it as a list

Outputs:

```
x
$id
[1] 1

$prod_info
  product brand price
1     xyz   pqr   500
2     abc   klm  5000

y
$id
[1] 1

$prod_info
$prod_info[[1]]
$prod_info[[1]]$product
[1] "xyz"

$prod_info[[1]]$brand
[1] "pqr"

$prod_info[[1]]$price
[1] 500


$prod_info[[2]]
$prod_info[[2]]$product
[1] "abc"

$prod_info[[2]]$brand
[1] "klm"

$prod_info[[2]]$price
[1] 5000

class(x$prod_info)
[1] "data.frame"

class(y$prod_info)
[1] "list"
```

Answer (score 1):

This difference made me go for **jsonlite**:

```
all.equal(mtcars, jsonlite::fromJSON(jsonlite::toJSON(mtcars)))
# Outputs
[1] TRUE
```

However:

```
all.equal(mtcars, rjson::fromJSON(rjson::toJSON(mtcars)))
# Outputs
[1] "Attributes: < names for target but not for current >"              "Attributes: < Length mismatch: comparison on first 0 components >"
```

Answer (score 0):

The question has already been answered, but regarding differences between the two packages, I got bitten by one recently: how empty dictionaries are handled.

With rjson

```
> rjson::fromJSON("[]")
list()
> rjson::fromJSON("{}")
list()
```

Whereas, with jsonlite:

```
> jsonlite::fromJSON("[]")
list()
> jsonlite::fromJSON("{}")
named list()
```

That is, with rjson, you can't tell the difference between an empty list and an empty dictionary.

The translation to JSON works with both however, e.g. `toJSON(structure(list(), names=character(0)))` yields `"{}"`.